# A better way than looping and calling functions that loop and call another functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, oop, design-patterns

I have a **message** (string) that is composed of **transactions** that is composed of **groups** that is composed of **elements**.

I there a better way to parse such message than *looping and calling functions* that *loop and call another functions* that *loop and call another functions* because I find the following is silly:

```
class Parser:
  def parse_msg(self, msg):
    trans = re.findall(trans_pattern, msg)
    for t in trans:
      self.parse_trans(t)

  def parse_trans(self, trans):
    groups = re.findall(groups_pattern, trans)
    for g in groups:
      self.parse_group(g)

  def parse_group(self, group):
    elements = re.findall(element_pattern, group)
    for e in elements:
      self.parse_element(e)

  def parse_element(self, e):
    pass
```

Is there a better way/**design-pattern** that I can approach this with?

Comment: If it's a specified grammar you could write a parser for it, e.g. using https://pypi.org/project/pyparsing/.

Comment: @deceze No it's not grammar, it's business based parser using some predefined standards.

Comment: Wut? You're trying to get information from a string, which presumably uses a defined structure (otherwise, good luck getting any information from it), so you could define that structure (grammar) in a parser like pyparsing.

Comment: @deceze sorry I misunderstand your comment and with a very quick look on PyParsing I thought it won't help but I'm definitely gonna check it more carefully. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is another way to parse - similar to SAX-parsing for xml. You can make tokenizer and then processor that calls functions according to tokens encoutered. You need to keep parsing context in one place available to each token function. It can be more effective if you like FSM stuff, but it's way more complicated code if you should fully parse message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method definitely sounds intensive since every bit of text will be gone over multiple times. O(n^3) complexity or something.

Instead, I would create a function to go through the input once and have it all parsed in one shot. To do that, it sounds like there's a handy pyparsing module you can use (I've never used it myself so I'm not sure of the learning curve, difficulty, or optimization). Otherwise, to do it manually, you'd have to keep track of your current "depth" (trans, group, or element) and determine if you're closing or opening a trans/group/element at that depth while keeping track of the data between opening and closing expressions. In short, don't find all "trans", just find where the first one begins, grab any unique data up until the next group begins, start the new group, grab unique data until the element begins, start the new element, grab data until it closes, see if there's another element or if the group closes, etc, etc. Not as concise, but certainly faster. If speed is not a concern, your method is fine. If it is (or will be) a concern, then you'll want to parse it in one pass.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I guess there are several possibilities. You could have some structure like the following:

```
import re

GRAMMAR = (
    trans_pattern, (
        groups_pattern, (
            element_pattern, None
        )
    )
)

def parse_message(msg):
    parse_message_rec(msg, GRAMMAR)

def parse_message_rec(msg, grammar):
    if grammar is None:
        # Leaf element
        return
    pattern, next_grammar = grammar
    children = re.findall(pattern, msg)
    for child in children:
        parse_message_rec(child, next_grammar)
```

Comment: Is it just me or is this just a fancy way to do exactly what he's already doing?

Comment: @CodeMonkey Yes, that's exactly it. My understanding is that OP wants some code that performs the same task with less code redundancy (and maybe more extendable/maintainable).

Comment: I was under the impression the OP was looking for optimization so that it's not as computationally expensive. In short, you're still looping and calling functions but doing it recursively with the same function rather than having multiple functions.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Yes, I am aware that the computational cost of my answer is the same. As I was saying, what I was trying to solve is the replication of nearly identical functions and loops. But it could be that the question was oriented towards performance instead of code quality (in which case it would take a significantly different approach to improve it, such as using a grammar parser as proposed in the comments).

Answer (score -2):

I order you the following method: convert you special format to simple XML (using regexp or what you prefer) and then you can apply any XML-pattern/method/library to parse your text.

Comment: Converting it to XML would simply double his efforts. He still has to parse it in its current format to do that which is the initial problem.